# Class Sofzo_From not found error when implementing Sozfo TinyMCE solution

Tags: forms, zend-framework, tinymce, textarea

I'm trying to implement TinyMCE to text areas using the solution mentioned in [Sofzo](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/100/improved-tinymce-solution-for-the-zend-framework#heading1). But when I try to extend the Sofzo_Form I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Sozfo_Form' not found in /home/foldername/public_html/application/forms/PageForm.php on line 4
```

What I have done so far -

Uploaded the Sofzo files to library with following directory structure

/library
../Sozfo
 
../Form.php
 
../../Form
 
../../../Element
 
../../../../TinyMce.php
 
../../View
 
../../../Helper
 
../../../Exception.php
 
../../../../FormTinyMce.php
 
../../../../TinyMce.php

Loaded the classes in application.ini as

```
Autoloadnamaspaces[] = "Sofzo_"
```

And in bootstrap as

```
 $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('Zend_');
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('SF_');
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('CMS_');
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('Sofzo_');

    $loader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader();
    $loader->addPrefixPath('Zend_View_Helper', 'Zend/View/Helper/')
           ->addPrefixPath('Storefront_View_Helper',
                           'application/modules/storefront/views/helpers')
                    ->addPrefixPath('Sozfo_Form', 'Sozfo/');

                    $view=new Zend_View();
                   $view->addHelperPath('Sozfo/View/Helper', 'Sozfo_View_Helper');
```

But when I try to extent the Sofzo_Form in Page_Form as

```
class Form_PageForm extends Sozfo_Form { }
```

This issue was solved thanks to Tim Fountain. But now when I load an element as

```
$this->addElement('tinyMce', 'message', array(
        'label' => 'Message',
        'required' => true,
        'cols' => '50',
        'rows' => '10',
        'editorOptions' => new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/tinymce.ini', 'moderator')
    ));
```

I get the following error

```
Plugin by name 'FormTinyMce' was not found in the registry
```

Read through several comments in original site and they are said to add

```
$view->addHelperPath('Sozfo/View/Helper', 'Sozfo_View_Helper');
```

to bootstrap. I've already done that, but I'm guessing I'm not doing something right. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the full error message - the error should show the include path after the bit you included. Also add the full autoloader setup from your bootstrap (where you setup `$autoLoader`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's actually the full error message I get. Updated the original with the full autoloader code in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is ZF can't find the class because it doesn't know about the `Sozfo_` namespace. You've attempted to register this namespace in two different ways, but both of them are incorrect.

In application.ini, you have:

```
Autoloadnamaspaces[] = "Sofzo_"
```

But this should be:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Sozfo_"
```

Then in the bootstrap you've tried to register it with:

```
$autoLoader->registerNamespace('Sofzo_');
```

but presumably this should be:

```
$autoLoader->registerNamespace('Sozfo_');
```

(note spelling). Which ever fix you apply you should only use one of these methods, as they do the same thing.

If it still doesn't work after that then there's an issue with your include_path.

**Edit**: To fix the view helper path, try this instead of the two lines you currently have:

```
$view = new Zend_View();

$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view);
$stack = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStack();
$stack->push($viewRenderer);

$view->addHelperPath('Sozfo/View/Helper', 'Sozfo_View_Helper');
```

This adds the helper path to a view object like you have but also supplies it to the view renderer (which is what renders all the view scripts). If you don't do this then the view renderer uses its own view object, so the view object you setup in the bootstrap is never used for anything.

If this doesn't work, try passing a full path as the first parameter to addHelperPath instead:

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/Sozfo/View/Helper', 'Sozfo_View_Helper');
```

Comment: Thanks a-lot, that pretty much solved the issue with extending the Sozfo_Form, now when I add an element I get another set of errors. Much appreciated if you can have a look on that too. Will update the original question.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) But when I add a new element with TinyMCE editor to the controller as specified above, it turns all the text areas in the controller to the tinymce editors. Any idea where the issue might be? Thanks.

Comment: That's down to the 'mode' configuration parameter for TinyMCE. You'll have to see whether Sozfo allows you to change that in the tinymce.ini configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work properly by setting a class attribute.